# Angular 8 Drag and Drop - dropping file or folder into an another folder

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk

By following the Angular CDK documentation, I could easily drag and drop things into the same list (one dimensional) or another list.

However, I am trying to drop an item (folder/link) into another item (folder) within the same list (multi-dimensional).

An array of objects - ex.

```
[
  {
    name: "Alpha",
    id: "Alpha",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Alpha 1",
        id: "Alpha-1",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Alpha 1.1",
            id: "Alpha-1.1"
          },
          {
            name: "Alpha 1.2",
            id: "Alpha-1.2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Alpha 2",
        id: "Alpha-2"
      },
      {
        name: "Alpha 3",
        id: "Alpha-3",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Alpha 3.1",
            id: "Alpha-3.1"
          },
          {
            name: "Alpha 3.2",
            id: "Alpha-3.2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Beta",
    id: "Beta"
  }
]
```

> In my structure, all objects who have children are the **Folders**, and leaf nodes are **Links**. Leaf nodes are hidden inside the parent folder. So, it formulates an exact directory like structure on the browser.

Now, I want to move **Beta** object into **Alpha**, so that it can be appended to the children of Alpha. That means each item can be dropped into all other visible folders.

I tried creating each item as `cdkDropList`, so that another item can be dragged into it.

Sample code,

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of getReportItems() | reportfilter:filterArg; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i"
cdkDrag 
[(cdkDragData)]="item"
cdkDragLockAxis="y" 
cdkDragBoundary="mat-nav-list"
cdkDropList
(cdkDragDropped)="drop($event)">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="item-wrapper {i}" (click)="onItemSelected(item)">
        <mat-icon *ngIf="item.children" mat-list-icon>folder</mat-icon>
        <i *ngIf="!item.children" mat-list-icon class="far fa-file-alt"></i>
        <span mat-line [ngClass]="{'objectiveClass': !item.children}">
           {{ item.name }}
        </span>
    </a>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

On drop event, it correctly passes dragged item data. However, how can I get the id of the dropped container? In event data, I have previousIndex and currentIndex both are 0 because each node is a different list. Hence each list only has one item at the 0th index.

I'm not sure if I'm doing correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

After some research and demo of Angular CDK, I realized that cdk drag and drop is not suitable for my need.

I achieved the desired result with HTML 5 Drag & Drop.

For detailed solution refer [this link](https://github.com/alerubis/angular-draggable-mat-tree)